# Number of solutions of solve() function in Maple 17

Tags: maple

I am using Maple 17 to solve equations. But when I use solve() function, it only return 1 solution while there are more than 1 solutions. How can I get all solutions of equations? This is my code:

```
rootss := solve({x^2-y^2 = 1, x^2+x*y = 2}, {x, y});
       { x = 2 RootOf\3 _Z  - 1/, y = RootOf\3 _Z  - 1/ }
evalf(rootss);
       {x = 1.154700539, y = 0.5773502693}
```

I tried to add options `maxsols` to funtion solve(), but results not change.

Answer (score 1):

If I add the option `explicit` to that `solve` call then I get two results, both in terms of explicit square-roots.

```
solve({x^2-y^2 = 1, x^2+x*y = 2},
      {x, y}, explicit);

   {x = (2/3)*3^(1/2), y = (1/3)*3^(1/2)},
   {x = -(2/3)*3^(1/2), y = -(1/3)*3^(1/2)}
```